# Qt based app, requirements to access a MySQL database

Tags: qt

There is a Qt5 based app which I developed, It access a MySQL database running in another machine.

The access to the database is ok with the app running in the machine I used to develop it. But I tried from another machine and it does not connect. There are no warnings about missing .DLLs.

What might be going on?

Comment: How do you deploy your application on other machine? Check http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html documentation, especially the plugin http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#qt-plugins

Comment: Post the error that you get.

Comment: I can't see any explicit errors. It just don't connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing `libmysql.dll`. Unfortunately, there was no indication of it during execution. And `windeployqt` do not track external deps like mysql dll.